# Align FORM input/submit button to right of form

Tags: css, forms, alignment

Currently I have a large input field - which is centered onmy screen, about 60-70% wide, & takes the full heightof the screen.

In the form, I have a SUBMIT buton, & this appears below the form (i need to scroll down the screen to see it).

i have tried css right align / floats & things - but this usually moves the actual form to the left/right, or puts the submit button flshed to the right of the screen (big gap between the form and the button).. The button is on the right - but still at the bottom of the html form.. off the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to

a) keep the main form in the middle/centre of the screen.

b) put the submit button on the right-top of the screen (next to the form)

I'll aso have a seperate submit button, i'll like to be under the first-button (using simple BR/  tag)

the latest/current code i have is:-

$mainboard.="\n\n";

(I echo the $mainboard value later - after ive done the calculations)...

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: Further My current table looks like this:-

<form ....>
<table style="margin-left:auto;    margin-right:auto; width:50%;">

(table contents)

</table><input type='submit' style='position: absolute; float:left; vertical-align:top;'></form>

Ive put the 'absolute' and float-left commands in the Table command & also the submit /input commands...

Comment: If i add floats - the whole table moves to the left of the screen &/or the submit button OVERLAPS the table.  are we allowed to put URLS of our website here ?

Answer (score 0):

set the position property of the submit property to `position: absolute` and set the float property to `float: left`